# Not able to fetch data while querying on Array of Json Objects in Laravel Postgresql

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5.7

I am trying to get all records whose id matches the given value.

**Laravel Version:** `laravel/framework: "5.7.*"`

**PHP Version:** `php: ^7.1.3"`

**psql -V**: `psql (PostgreSQL) 11.1 (Ubuntu 11.1-1.pgdg16.04+1)`

Below is the structure of table and postgres sql query with sample data.

[image: DB]

**subscribed_places** column contains -> `[{"id":1},{"id":4}]`

From laravel I am using below code.

```
return Vendor::whereJsonContains('subscribed_places->id', 1)
            ->get();
```

since value **1** is present it should return this record but its giving 0 results even if **4** is passed.

**Vendor Model Class**

```
class Vendor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vendor';

    protected $casts = [
        'subscribed_places' => 'array',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at', 'updated_at',,
    ];
}
```

**Migration File**

```
class CreateVendorTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vendor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('vendor_code', 30)->unique();
            $table->json('subscribed_places');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```

**2nd Approach (not working)**

[image]

```
return Vendor::whereJsonContains('subscribed_places', '{"id":1}')
            ->get();
```

Still returns 0 records.

Comment: you cant used `json_decode` and next apply `filter` on array and test if is `json` valid

Comment: Try using `Vendor::whereJsonContains('subscribed_places', '{"id":1}')` you can take a look [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iD89grjCdEwqbPti26SuN6/0)

Comment: @Vixed not working I am using postgres and i have put snapshot of it the above question post.

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos  you mean to say remove $casts from Vendor model right.. I tried it but still gives 0 results.

Comment: @Vixed from the link which you have shared is actually showing using MySql try changing to postgreSql and test.. it fails